# $O_S$ is the integral closure of $k[T]$ in $F$ for some embedding of $k(T)$ in $F$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-geometry, field-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $F$ be a function field in one variable over a field $k$. Let $S$ be a nonempty finite subset of the set of all places of $F$. Let$$O_S = \{f \in F: \text{ord}_v(f) \ge 0 \text{ for all }X \setminus S\}.$$How do I show that for $f$ as in [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1285237/poles-of-a-sum-of-functions?rq=1) and for the embedding $k(T) \to F$ which sends $T$ to $f$, $O_S$ coincides with the integral closure of $k[T]$ in $F$?

I have shown the following so far:

- If $f \in F$ is not algebraic over $k$, then $F$ is a finite extension of the field $k(f)$.
- If $f \in F$ is algebraic over $k$ and $f \neq 0$, then $\text{ord}_v(f) = 0$ for any $v \in X$.

But I am not sure what do from here on out.

Comment: What do you mean by `$f$ as in here'? There are many such $f$ and which one are you picking? For example, I could have picked $f=1$, but clearly, ypu do not even have an embedding $k(T)\to F$ sending $T$ to 1.

Comment: Just wondering: are you using a new account for every new posted question?